# My controller is strafing left when I hit both triggers

Tags: ps4, controllers, warframe

So, I've been playing Warframe lately, and I've noticed that occasionally, when I aim (hold LT) and then fire (hold RT) I strafe left.

I have done some testing, and I have found that it's less consistent if I stop moving before I aim, then fire. It also occasionally triggers if I move while I'm aiming and shooting.

I think it might be a dodgy input in the controller? But I'm not sure. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Stick Drift.

Simply put, your controller may be off by a small amount. This can happen for a variety of reasons.

[Test for stick drift and recalibrate.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCEISv4SaUM)
Should not be too hard, with access to a pc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to add it to my question, but it has only occurred recently that I know of, and the controller of fairly old, would that have any impact?

Comment: @Ben Yes. Wear-and-tear and build-up of dirt are both very common causes of stick drift in older, well-used, controllers. [Replacing or cleaning the sticks are the respective solutions](https://devicetests.com/why-does-your-controller-drift)